# The function must accept the result of another function as an argument Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

The result of the gen function must be an argument of the res function.
The result of the res function is even numbers that came out of the first function.

```kotlin
fun gen():List<Int>{
    val numbers=List(10){Random.nextInt(1,100)}
    return numbers.filter{it>0}
}
fun res(){...}
```

Comment: What do you mean? What is your exact question?

Comment: natural random numbers should be output when you click on the first button of the app, then only even numbers should be output when you click on the second button

Answer (score 1):

From your question, seems like you're trying to create list of random numbers and then filtering out the even numbers from the generated list.

Most probably this should be the implementation:

```kotlin
fun gen(): List<Int> = List(10) { Random.nextInt(1, 100) }

fun res(list: List<Int>) = list.filter { it % 2 == 0 }

// somewhere else
val generated = gen()
println(generated)
println(res(generated))
```

Sample output:

```
[44, 57, 64, 96, 30, 93, 92 23, 58, 26]
[44, 64, 96, 30, 92, 58, 26]
```

Comment: You could store result of gen() in a variable then.

Comment: I' m asking about. How to do it?  Tell me please

Comment: @NikPo check now

Comment: @ Animesh Sahu One problem.I need to output the result not to the console but to Android using return. How can this be implemented in your code?

Comment: @NikPo use your logic man, you never provided any info about those